# Css differs when hosting my website on hostinger

Tags: php, html, css, localhost, web-hosting

i build my website and run it on localhost it work.
when i upload it on Hostinger a problem occurred with my CSS for my calendar
what may the problem be?

On localhost:
[image: here when i run on localhost]

On Hostinger:
[image: here when it is on hostinger (button in the middle of the calendar day]

i try to change with css to find the problem, but not working
like i try to move the buttons but it not moving

Css:

```
body {
    font-family: "Arial";
}
 
div#calendar {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 602px;
}
 
div#calendar div.box {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #3FA7D6;
}
 
div#calendar div.header {
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: 11px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 582px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
div#calendar div.header a.prev, div#calendar div.header a.next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 17px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
 
div#calendar div.header span.title {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
}
 
div#calendar div.header a.prev {
    left: 0px;
}
 
div#calendar div.header a.next {
    right: 0px;
}
 
/*******************************Calendar Content Cells*********************************/
div#calendar div.box-content {
    border: 1px solid #3FA7D6;
    border-top: none;
}
 
div#calendar ul.label {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
 
div#calendar ul.label li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 
div#calendar ul.dates {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
 
/** overall width = width+padding-right**/
div#calendar ul.dates li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
 
:focus {
    outline: none;
}
 
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
 
li div {
    display: flex;
}
 
li div form {
    display: inline;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
}
 
div.open {
    background: #04AA6D;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
 
div.booked {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: inherit;
}
 

 
.submit:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.submit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
  
}
```

Calender html

```
<?php
 
class Calendar
{
 
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
 
    /********************* PROPERTY ********************/
    public $cellContent = '';
    protected $observers = array();
 
    private $dayLabels = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
    private $currentYear = 0;
    private $currentMonth = 0;
    private $currentDay = 0;
    private $currentDate = null;
    private $daysInMonth = 0;
    private $sundayFirst = true;
    private $naviHref = null;
 
    /********************* PUBLIC **********************/
    /* @return void
     * @access public
     */
    public function attachObserver($type, $observer)
    {
        $this->observers[$type][] = $observer;
    }
 
    /*
    *
    * @return void
    * @access public
    */
    public function notifyObserver($type)
    {
        if (isset($this->observers[$type])) {
            foreach ($this->observers[$type] as $observer) {
                $observer->update($this);
            }
        }
    }
 
    public function getCurrentDate()
    {
        return $this->currentDate;
    }
 
    /**
     * Set week labels' order.
     * When it is set to false,
     * monday will be listed as the first day.
     *
     * @param boolean
     * @return              void
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              public
     */
    public function setSundayFirst($bool = true)
    {
        $this->sundayFirst = $bool;
    }
 
    /**
     * print out the calendar
     *
     * @param string
     * @param string
     * @param array
     * @return              string
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              public
     */
    public function show($month = null, $year = null, $attributes = false)
    {
        if (null == $year && isset($_GET['year'])) {
            $year = $_GET['year'];
        } else if (null == $year) {
            $year = date("Y", time());
        }
 
        if (null == $month && isset($_GET['month'])) {
            $month = $_GET['month'];
        } else if (null == $month) {
            $month = date("m", time());
        }
 
        $this->currentYear = $year;
        $this->currentMonth = $month;
        $this->daysInMonth = $this->_daysInMonth($month, $year);
 
        $content = '<div id="calendar">' .
            '<div class="box">' .
            $this->_createNavi() .
            '</div>' .
            '<div class="box-content">' .
            '<ul class="label">' . $this->_createLabels() . '</ul>';
        $content .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
        $content .= '<ul class="dates">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->_weeksInMonth($month, $year); $i++) {
            for ($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j++) {
                $content .= $this->_showDay($i * 7 + $j, $attributes);
                 
            }
        }
        $content .= '</ul>';
        $content .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        return $content;
    }
 
    /********************* PRIVATE **********************/
    /**
     * create the li element for ul
     *
     * @param string
     * @param array
     * @return              string
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              private
     */
    private function _showDay($cellNumber, $attributes = false)
    {
        if ($this->currentDay == 0) {
            //1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
            $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N', strtotime($this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-01'));
            if ($this->sundayFirst) {
                if ($firstDayOfTheWeek == 7) {
                    $firstDayOfTheWeek = 1;
                } else {
                    $firstDayOfTheWeek++;
                }
            }
            if (intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)) {
                $this->currentDay = 1;
            }
        }
 
        if (($this->currentDay != 0) && ($this->currentDay <= $this->daysInMonth)) {
            $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-' . ($this->currentDay)));
            $cellContent = $this->_createCellContent($attributes);
            $this->currentDay++;
        } else {
            $this->currentDate = null;
            $cellContent = null;
        }
 
 
        return '<li id="li-' . $this->currentDate . '" class="' . ($cellNumber % 7 == 1 ? ' start ' : ($cellNumber % 7 == 0 ? ' end ' : ' ')) .
            ($cellContent == null ? 'mask' : '') . '">' . $cellContent .'</li>';
    }
 
    /**
     * create navigation
     *
     * @return              string
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              private
     */
    private function _createNavi()
    {
        $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth == 12 ? 1 : intval($this->currentMonth) + 1;
        $nextYear = $this->currentMonth == 12 ? intval($this->currentYear) + 1 : $this->currentYear;
 
        $preMonth = $this->currentMonth == 1 ? 12 : intval($this->currentMonth) - 1;
        $preYear = $this->currentMonth == 1 ? intval($this->currentYear) - 1 : $this->currentYear;
 
        return
            '<div class="header">' .
            '<a class="prev" href="' . $this->naviHref . '?month=' . sprintf('%02d', $preMonth) . '&year=' . $preYear . '">Prev</a>' .
            '<span class="title">' . date('Y M', strtotime($this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-1')) . '</span>' .
            '<a class="next" href="' . $this->naviHref . '?month=' . sprintf("%02d", $nextMonth) . '&year=' . $nextYear . '">Next</a>' .
            '</div>';
    }
 
    /**
     * create calendar week labels
     *
     * @return              string
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              private
     */
    private function _createLabels()
    {
        if ($this->sundayFirst) {
            $temp = $this->dayLabels[0];
            for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($this->dayLabels); $i++) {
                $tmp = $this->dayLabels[$i];
                $this->dayLabels[$i] = $temp;
                $temp = $tmp;
            }
            $this->dayLabels[0] = $temp;
        }
 
 
        $content = '';
        foreach ($this->dayLabels as $index => $label) {
            $content .= '<li class="' . ($label == 6 ? 'end title' : 'start title') . ' title">' . $label . '</li>';
        }
 
        return $content;
    }
 
    /**
     * create content for li element
     *
     * @param array
     * @return              string
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              private
     */
    private function _createCellContent($setting = false)
    {
        $this->cellContent = '';
 
        $this->cellContent = $this->currentDay;
 
        //observer
        $this->notifyObserver('showCell');
 
        return $this->cellContent;
    }
 
    /**
     * calculate number of weeks in a particular month
     *
     * @param number
     * @param number
     * @return              number
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              private
     */
    private function _weeksInMonth($month = null, $year = null)
    {
        if (null == ($year))
            $year = date("Y", time());
 
        if (null == ($month))
            $month = date("m", time());
 
        // find number of weeks in this month
        $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month, $year);
 
        $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1) + intval($daysInMonths / 7);
        $monthEndingDay = date('N', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $daysInMonths));
        $monthStartDay = date('N', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));
        $monthEndingDay == 7 ? $monthEndingDay = 0 : '';
        $monthStartDay == 7 ? $monthStartDay = 0 : '';
 
        if ($monthEndingDay < $monthStartDay) {
            $numOfweeks++;
        }
        return $numOfweeks;
 
    }
 
    /**
     * calculate number of days in a particular month
     *
     * @param number
     * @param number
     * @return              number
     * @author              The-Di-Lab <thedilab@gmail.com>
     * @access              private
     */
    private function _daysInMonth($month = null, $year = null)
    {
        if (null == ($year))
            $year = date("Y", time());
 
        if (null == ($month))
            $month = date("m", time());
 
        return date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));
    }
 
}
```

And here the part must move button

```
.submit:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.submit:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty uncommon that the style differs. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to move the button up or down but also dont work it stay in the middle

Comment: Inspect the elements in question using your browser dev tools, and check which styles apply. Also check that the HTML / DOM structure is actually identical.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem on my website yesterday. I loaded my website to look at it, then upload files to hosting, and CSS was messed up. I was thinking it is something with CSS or hosting, but the reason was Google Chrome. When I loaded on Edge it worked as intended.

The solution was to clear cookies and cache in the browser.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34621861)

Comment: It does answer the question. Clearing cookies in browser fixed in my case the same problem this guy have. Therfore it could solve the same problem for other people too.